# What is the formula of calculating the era points in polkadot?

Tags: polkadot, staking, rewards, era, eraindex

I've been delving into the era points system on Polkadot, but I'm encountering confusion regarding how the total points for validators are calculated. There are currently 297 active validators, and in one era, a total of 14,400 blocks are produced. If each block contributes 20 era points, then the total era points for the era would be 288,000. Then how in the storage of the erasRewardpoints in pallet staking is showing 28,206,520 of one era ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past, it is 20 only.

---

Now, validators will also be rewarded for participating in parachains with era points in pallet-staking.

Check

- https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/runtimes/blob/8b7b1cb5822c76dec7dd75e07bfdee36bab41a15/relay/polkadot/src/lib.rs#L1297
- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/ea5f4e9a4d78234eb68bbb9130a24b0598c7893a/polkadot/runtime/parachains/src/reward_points.rs#L35.